# Negatives not adding well

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

The code is here

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout << 1 + -4 << "\n";
    signed int x1; //(x1, ...
    signed int y1; //(x1, y1)...
    signed int x2; //... (x2, ...
    signed int y2; // ... (x2, y2)
    signed int ans1;
    signed int ans2;
    signed int ans3;
    signed int result;
    cout << "X1: ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "\nY1: ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "\nX2: ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "\nY2: ";
    cin >> y2;
    cout << "\n(" << x1 << ", " << y1 << "), (" << x2 << ", " << y2 << ")\n";
    result = (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1);
    cout << "X2 - X1 = " << x2 - x1 << "\n";
    cout << "Y2 - Y1 = " << y2 - y1 << "\n";
    ans1 = x2 - x1;
    ans2 = y2 - y1;
    ans3 = ans1 + ans2;
    cout << ans1 << " + " << ans2 << " = " << ans3;
    cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to make a solver for a simple equation. In it's simple terms, it is (x2 - x1)(squared) + (y2 - y1)(squared) - as in those are different numbers - think coordinates. (4, 3), (6, 2)

The problem is that, as an example, when I enter 8, 6, 9, 2 (which turns out to be (8, 6), (9, 2) it brings out the wrong answer than when I solve it on paper. I went ahead and made it cout << the steps in order, and it says that 1 + -4 is -317. I am very confused as this is nowhere near the right answer, of course. So what is wrong? It does break when I removed the signed from the beginning integers.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012, running Windows 8.

Comment: Please don't be mean about it, it was a simple accident. I meant Visual Studio 2012. I am using a C++ Console Application for it as well.

Comment: Feel free to use that "edit" link to fix your question.

Answer (score 4):

So I see the same thing you do: http://ideone.com/jaGeXx

> 1 + -4 = -317

is created by these *two* lines in your code:

```
cout << ans1 << " + " << ans2 << " = " << ans3;
cout << result << "\n";
```

The first generates

> 1 + -1 = -3

The second generates

> 17

And you didn't ask for any separating newline or whitespace. so your program happily sent them to the screen right next to each other.

Comment: I missed that. I'm sorry, I should honestly look this over before turning to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

-3 is -3.

(-1)-squared plus 4-squared is 17.

Make sure you print a newline between -3 and 17.